# Implementing a skype web service in a php application

Tags: php, web-services, skype

I am making a web application using php, and I would like to implement a web service that shows whether I am online with my skype account or not, on one of the pages.

Is this a possible thing to do? And if it is, how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skype button! [See skype buttons here.](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/)

Just get the HTML code for your Skype username and put it in your HTML source code. You do need to activate "Show online status" from your Skype preferences (from the options in the Skype application itself).

Comment: Thanks mate, that was exactly what I was looking for! Didn't know there was such a useful component for skype.

Comment: To help you in the future, these are usually called "status indicators".